# Polynomial with given roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have the following question. Given the following expresion

$$r_{1}= \frac{e+ \frac{1}{2}(f+f^{\prime})t_{1}}{E+ Ft_{1}}= \frac{ \frac{1}{2}(f+f^{\prime})+ gt_{1}}{F+ Gt_{1}},$$

$$r_{2}= \frac{e+ \frac{1}{2}(f+f^{\prime})t_{2}}{E+ Ft_{2}}= \frac{ \frac{1}{2}(f+f^{\prime})+ gt_{2}}{F+ Gt_{2}}.$$

Where $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ satisfies

$$ t_{1}+t_{2}= \frac{eG-Ge}{gF-\frac{1}{2}(f+ f^{\prime})G}, \hspace{4mm}  t_{1}t_{2}= \frac{\frac{1}{2}(f+ f^{\prime})E -eF}{gF-\frac{1}{2}(f+ f^{\prime})G}.$$

My question arose since in the guide text book the author says, If one eliminates t1 or t2 from these equations then one will obtain the following  quadratic equation, whose roots $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$

$$ (EF-F^{2})r^{2} + (gE-(f+f^{\prime})F+ eG)r+ eg-\frac{1}{4}(f+ f^{\prime})^{2}=0$$

But I don't understand what means elimanate $t_{1}$ or $t_{2}$.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The equation with roots $r_1,r_2$ is $r^2 - (r_1+r_2) r + r_1r_2 = 0$. Both $r_1+r_2$ and $r_1r_2$ are symmetric expressions in $t_1,t_2$, so they can be expressed in terms of $t_1+t_2$ and $t_1t_2$. Once you do that and complete the calculations, you should be getting the last equation.

Comment: Thanks. I put the expressions $r1 = (e + (1/2 (f + h) t1))/(E2 + F t1)$ ;
$r2 = (e + (1/2 (f + h) t2))/(E2 + F t2)$;
Collect[FullSimplify[$r^2 + (r1 + r2) r + r1 r2$], r], $t_{1}, t_{2}$ and it works.

Comment: You should define and work with fewer constants since the way you have it now obfuscates it, but what you basically want/need to do is eliminate $t$ between $r = \frac{at+b}{ct+d}$ and $t^2 - st+p=0$ in order to get the equivalent quadratic in $r$.

Comment: Maybe, the book author wants to reach a polynomial free of $t_1$ and $t_2$. As a result, you need the final quadratic equation to "not depend on" these 2 variables. This requires defining r1, r2 to be defined without reference to  $t_1$ and $t_2$ since the quadratic equation coefficients are related to the roots as @dxiv said in 1st comment above. As a starting point try to solve for $t1$ and $t2$ using $t1+t2=X$ and $t1.t2=Y$, then substitute in the top 2 equations $r1=...$ and $r2=...$. This way r1 and r2 will be free of $t1$ and $t2$.